# when opened a new frame and then going back to the home page, the home page messes up

Tags: python, tkinter

when I sign in everything is fine and it takes me to the home page, when I click on  view menu and then click the back button it takes me back to the home page, everything is still fine and the way I want **however** when I click on order menu and then press the back button to go back to the home page, my home page messes up and I see parts of **"function:**" function, how can i fix this?
I'm sorry if the code is a bit long I already cut out most of the unnecessary code (or tried to). Thank you for your help

from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('670x466')

accounts = []
food = ['Pizza','Burger','Nachos', 'French Toast']
foodprice=['20','9.50','7.50', '17']
drinks = ['Pepsi','Lemonade','Tea', 'Aperitivo Spritz']
drinksprice = ['3','4','3', '15.50']

class Goode_brothers:


def __init__(self, parent):

    self.myFrame = Frame(parent)
    self.myFrame.pack()


    self.load = Image.open('new-dip-project\\food.jpg')
    self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load)
    self.img = Label(parent, image = self.render)
    self.img.place(x = -26, y =0)

    self.img_login = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\button (3).png')
    self.b1 = Button(parent,image = self.img_login, command = self.read_info, bd = 0, bg = '#3b353b', activebackground = '#3b353b')
    self.b1.place(x = 275, y = 340)



    self.img_register = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\register.png')
    self.b2 = Button(parent,image = self.img_register, command = self.openNewWindow, bd = 0, bg = '#3b353b', activebackground = '#3b353b')
    self.b2.place(x = 265, y = 400)

    self.canvas = Canvas(parent, width = 400, height = 120)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('new-dip-project\\goode.png'))
    self.canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=self.img4)



    self.email = Entry(parent)
    self.email.place(x = 340, y = 180)

    self.password = Entry(parent)
    self.password.place(x = 354, y = 250)

    self.img_label = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label-image.png')
    self.name = Label(parent, image = self.img_label, text = "Email:", bg = '#3c3a3b').place(x = 197,y = 178)

    self.img_label_pass = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label_pass.png')
    self.name = Label(parent, image = self.img_label_pass, text = "Password:", bg = '#3c3a3b').place(x = 177,y = 245)




def openMenu(self):

    for wid in root.winfo_children():
        wid.destroy()
    self.myFrame.destroy()

    self.myFrame2 = Frame(root, bg = '')
    self.myFrame2.pack(fill = "both", expand = 1)


    self.img77 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\goode.png')
    self.name77 = Label(self.myFrame2, image = self.img77).pack()

    self.img_menu = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\menu_button.png')
    self.b6 = Button(self.myFrame2,image = self.img_menu, command = self.view_menu, bd  = 0)
    self.b6.place(x = 246, y = 140)

    self.img_order = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\order_button.png')
    self.b7 = Button(self.myFrame2,image = self.img_order, command = self.order_menu, bd  = 0)
    self.b7.place(x = 239, y = 228)

    self.img_checkout = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\checkout.png')
    self.b8 = Button(self.myFrame2,image = self.img_checkout, bd  = 0)
    self.b8.place(x = 250, y = 316)



def view_menu(self):

    self.myFrame2.destroy()
    self.myFrame3 = LabelFrame(root, height = 700)
    self.myFrame3.pack()

    self.myFrame3.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.myFrame3.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)

    self.food_title = Label(self.myFrame3, font=("Impact", "23"), text = 'Food').grid(row = 0, column = 4)
    self.food_space = Label(self.myFrame3, text = '').grid(row = 1, column = 4)
    self.drinks_title = Label(self.myFrame3, font=("Impact", "23"), text = 'Drinks').grid(row = 8, column = 4)

    self.price = Label(self.myFrame3, font=("Impact", "23"), text = 'Price($)').grid(row = 0, column = 8)


    for x in range (len(food)):
        self.foodop = Label(self.myFrame3, font=("Impact", "15"), text = food[x]).grid(row = 3+x, column = 4) #A created label defining where it is positioned
        self.fprice = Label(self.myFrame3, font=("Impact", "15"), text = foodprice[x]).grid(row = 3+x, column = 8)

    for x in range (len(drinks)):
        self.drinksop = Label(self.myFrame3, font=("Impact", "15"), text = drinks[x]).grid(row = 5+(len(food))+x, column = 4)
        self.drinksp = Label(self.myFrame3, font=("Impact", "15"), text = drinksprice[x]).grid(row = 5+(len(food))+x, column = 8)


    self.img_back = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\back_button.png')
    self.b10 = Button(self.myFrame3,image = self.img_back, command = self.openMenu, bd  = 0)
    self.b10.grid(row = 38, column = 7)



def order_menu(self):
    for wid2 in root.winfo_children():
        wid2.destroy()
    self.myFrame2.destroy()
    self.myFrame4 = Frame(root)
    self.myFrame4.pack(fill = "both", expand = 1)

    self.tkvar = StringVar(self.myFrame4)
    self.tkvar.set("Food")

    self.tkvar2 = StringVar(self.myFrame4)
    self.tkvar2.set("Drinks")

    self.img_odmenu = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\od_menu.png')
    self.order_menu_message = Label(self.myFrame4, image = self.img_odmenu).place(x = 220)

    self.foodMenu = OptionMenu(self.myFrame4, self.tkvar, *food)
    self.foodMenu.place(x = 160, y = 110)

    self.Foodlabel = Label(self.myFrame4, text="Choose Your Food", font=("Courier New","12"))
    self.Foodlabel.place(x = 145, y = 83)

    self.drinklabel = Label(self.myFrame4, text="Choose Your Drink", font=("Courier New","12"))
    self.drinklabel.place(x = 370, y = 83)

    self.drinkMenu = OptionMenu(self.myFrame4, self.tkvar2, *drinks)
    self.drinkMenu.place(x = 385, y = 110)

    self.pricelabel = Label(self.myFrame4, text = "Total price", font=("Courier New","12"))
    self.pricelabel.place(x = 289, y = 208)

    self.order_btn78 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\orderb.png')
    self.order_btn = Button(self.myFrame4, image = self.order_btn78, bd = 0)
    self.order_btn.place(x = 302, y = 160)

    self.check_btn = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\checkpay.png')
    self.checkout_btn = Button(self.myFrame4, image = self.check_btn, bd = 0)
    self.checkout_btn.place(x = 267, y = 410)

    self.img_odmenu = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\od_menu.png')
    self.order_menu_message = Label(self.myFrame4, image = self.img_odmenu).place(x = 220)

    self.foodMenu = OptionMenu(self.myFrame4, self.tkvar, *food)
    self.foodMenu.place(x = 160, y = 110)

    self.Foodlabel = Label(self.myFrame4, text="Choose Your Food", font=("Courier New","12"))
    self.Foodlabel.place(x = 145, y = 83)

    self.drinklabel = Label(self.myFrame4, text="Choose Your Drink", font=("Courier New","12"))
    self.drinklabel.place(x = 370, y = 83)

    self.drinkMenu = OptionMenu(self.myFrame4, self.tkvar2, *drinks)
    self.drinkMenu.place(x = 385, y = 110)

    self.pricelabel = Label(self.myFrame4, text = "Total price", font=("Courier New","12"))
    self.pricelabel.place(x = 289, y = 208)

    self.order_btn78 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\orderb.png')
    self.order_btn = Button(self.myFrame4, image = self.order_btn78, bd = 0)
    self.order_btn.place(x = 302, y = 160)

    self.check_btn = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\checkpay.png')
    self.checkout_btn = Button(self.myFrame4, image = self.check_btn, bd = 0)
    self.checkout_btn.place(x = 267, y = 410)

    self.back_menu = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\bbutton.png')
    self.back_button2 = Button(self.myFrame4, image = self.back_menu, command = self.openMenu, bd  = 0)
    self.back_button2.place(x = 30, y = 410)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    e = Goode_brothers(root)
    root.title('Goode brothers')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What I suggest is If you want to go back, to the main page, then you should not destroy the frame or the widgets, instead, you should hide the frame by using ```place_forget()``` or ```pack_forget()``` or ```grid_forget()``` if you have used ```.place```,```.pack``` or ```.grid``` respectively

Comment: You haven't provided ```back_menu```

Comment: i want the function "def openMenu(self):" to run when i press this button     "self.back_button2 = Button(self.myFrame4, image = self.back_menu, command = self.openMenu, bd  = 0)" haven't i already done that? it works and takes me back to the home page but the home page appearance looks like the 3rd picture i sent in my post, i want it to look like the 1st picture.

Comment: I don't understand why are you destroying the frame. You should use ```pack_forget()``` instead of  ```for widget in root.winfo_children()``` and ```widget.destroy()``` and then ```frame.destroy()```

Comment: And also, why are you passing ```root``` as a parent? ```parent``` should be there ,right?

Comment: when i use "pack_forget()"  in "def order_menu(self):" function it still doesn't fix it, when i use pack_forget() in any other function than "def order_menu(self):" everything goes into disarray and when i try to sign in the sign in page frame and the home frame (def openMenu(self):) mix up. and I'm not too sure what you mean by your last comment since I'm new to GUI, I'm sorry

Comment: I tried updating your code. Check if that's working?

Comment: Remove `bg = ''` from `self.self.myFrame2 = Frame(root, bg = '')`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to indent the methods under the class Goode Brothers